# chrome extension with Facebook OAuth not allow wildcard, but

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, google-chrome-extension

[image: inline]

All the tutorials for the chrome extension with FB Oauth login is to use `chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()`

But it doesn't make sense at all. Because FB OAuth not allow wildcard in the redirect url. and `chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()` will change everytime.

Even I point the redirect url to my Rails server.

I could only get the redirect url without any valid token.

```
params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"redirect"=>"https://daeooffnjhgchmfmebclagekadcdalhm.chromiumapp.org/", "format"=>"json", "controller"=>"api/v1/query_words", "action"=>"fbLogin"} permitted: false>
```

>

```
var CHROME_POPUP_URL = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL();
var FACEBOOK_LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL= 'https://638b5bb3.ngrok.io/api/v1/fbLogin?redirect='+encodeURIComponent(CHROME_POPUP_URL);
var BASE = 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?'
var FACEBOOK_OAUTH_URL = BASE+'response_type=code%20token' +'&client_id='+clientID+'&redirect_uri='+CHROME_POPUP_URL+'&scope='+FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS;


        let params = {
            url: FACEBOOK_OAUTH_URL,
            interactive: true
        }
        console.log(params)
        chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
            params
```

Comment: Try to check this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login) if it can help you to authorize your application with Facebook. Just check the Advanced tab to check how to manually build a login flow. Also, check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312547/how-get-facebook-token-using-oauth2-with-chrome-identity) if it can help you.